# Bot Framework - Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime Metadata Error

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I have created a brand new, empty ASP.NET Web Application project. I have added the `Microsoft.Bot.Builder` NuGet package which also adds `Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime`.

Now whenever I try to use NuGet to install other packages (in this instance `CsvHelper`) I get the following error:

**An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.2.3.2' from source 'D:\Projects\Bot\packages'.**

This is the same error I get when I try to add any Nuget packages to an existing Bot Framework project also. It appears there are issues with the `Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime` package.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Just check it out first.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37618663
I have had a similar issue before. Remove [Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime] from the package.config, then add your target package and restore the [Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime].