# An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Microsoft.CSharp.4.3.0'

Tags: c#, nuget

All,

I have just updated the .Net framework to 4.5 and re-installed Microsoft.CSharp (as it was showing a yellow icon next to it under my reference folder).

Now every time I try to install or update **ANY** package from Nuget, I get the following error in red:

An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Microsoft.CSharp.4.3.0'

I also tried to update the Nuget Package Sources to the following at different time but to no avail:
https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc

Can anyone shed some light on the above?

Comment: what do you mean by 're-installed Microsoft.CSharp'?

Comment: Hi Lei Yang, Within my solution, under References, there is a Microsoft.CSharp dll that had a yellow warning Icon next to it. I deleted and re installed that from Nuget BECAUSE of that yellow warning Icon.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this error by opening packages.config and removing the line that references Micrsoft.CSharp.4.3.0

See [nuget retrieving package metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33617584/nuget-retrieving-package-metadata)