# An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3'

Tags: c#, packet

I get an error while I install new package in Visual studio I have this error

```
 An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2'
```

I had update it from `Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2` to `Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.3` But I have the same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nuget retrieving package metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33617584/nuget-retrieving-package-metadata)

Comment: How I can Solve it

Answer (score 0):

I try to upgrade my nuget and it work with Me