# An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.2.1.1'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget

I deleted nuget cashe with command

```
nuget locals all -clear
```

After that, I couldn't run a project. My project is in ASP.NET Core 2. It shows this error message

```
 error : An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.2.1.1' from source 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder'
```

I tried dotnet restore, the same mistake. I tried to reinstall packages but nothing helps. Any suggestions for fixing this problem or explanation of the problem?

My project file contains :

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, , processorArchitecture=MSIL"> 
 <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll</HintPath> 
</Reference>
```

Comment: The current version is 3.1.2. Do you have a hard-coded reference to `2.1.1` or that specific path? What does your `csproj` look like? Especially the `PackageReference` element that adds `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory`

Comment: The package may be added as an indirect reference. In that case, check `project.assets.json` in the `obj` folder. This file lists all dependencies hierarchically.

Comment: This is in csproj file

`<Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, , processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>`

Comment: I believe you will find this answer from another user quite helpful. 
Give it a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37618663/8293694.
In my opinion the 2 questions are similar.

Comment: In the question itself please! That's a problem though - it's a *direct* reference to a specific local file, not a `PackageReference`. How was this package added?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the DLL was added manually, without actually adding the package. Or the project was migrated from the old .NET Framework format without moving the package references to it.

NuGet packages are added through the [PackageReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) tag. The project file should contain :

```
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- ... -->
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory" Version="2.2.0" />
    <!-- ... -->
</ItemGroup>
```

`Reference` adds a reference to a local DLL. That DLL has to be present, either in the SDK or the local folder pointed by `HintPath`. In this case, the `Reference` tag should be removed.